# How to get remote file size to increment progress bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf, uiprogressview

i need to download large pdf from web and i created a progress bar controller.

[image]

But, how i set max progress value it i don't know the pdf size before downloading?
Is there a way to get file size and use it to increment progress bar?

I'm using

```
myPDFremoteUrl = "http://www.xasdaxxssxx.pdf";
- (float) getFileSize {
    NSFileManager *man = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: myPDFremoteUrl error: NULL];
    UInt32 result = [attrs fileSize];

    return (float)result;
}
```

but i don't able to check remote size in this way...

any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for your data retrieval. It has [progress monitoring built in](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#progress).

If you really want to stick with what you've got, you can look at the HTTP header. It has a property called "Content-Length" that will help you out.

Good luck.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest does not work properly in iOS5 and the developer is no longer maintaining the project.  I suggest you look elsewhere for this functionality, for instance, CFNetworking.

Answer (score 1):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) has a `downloadProgressDelegate` that can handle this for you- its very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    dimensione = (float)[response expectedContentLength];

    NSLog(@"content-length: %f bytes", dimensione);
}
```

I forget `didReceiveResponse`!

good.

Comment: In your code in what data type you have declared for dimensione.